# Spring security access roles inside a method

Tags: spring, spring-security

In Spring security is it possible to get roles and properties the user might have associated with their token inside a method?

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(T(ROLES.Admin)")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<base> save(@RequestBody body) throws URISyntaxException {
    // here i want to get all the data associated whit this user ie. jwt token
    // roles etc .. as i need to pass this on
}
```

I have seen you can get the principal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you can get it through `Principal`.like this:

```
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
user.getAuthorities();
```